# Python cv2 not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Can someone tell me whats going wrong here?

```
line 11, in <module>
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import cv2

filename = "C:\\Users\\Tony\\Pictures\\img807.tif"
img = cv.imread(filename, 0)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv.moments(cnt)
print(M)
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.findContours` return two values (contours and hierarchy) not three.

So it solve the error replace by:

```
contours, hierarchy = = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```